# understanding the following proof of galois theory.

Tags: galois-theory

[image]I was studying Galois Theory from the notes available on NPTEL. I am having difficulty in last line of the proof.
If $\delta\notin F$, then how can we conclude that $E^{G_{f} \cap A_{n}} = F(\delta)$.
Here $A_{n}$ is subgroup containing even permutations of permutation group $S_n$ and $G_f$ is galois group of polynomial $f$.

Answer (score 0):

The group $G_f$ is the Galois group of $E$ over $F$, so $F = E^{G_f}$.  We have

$$F = E^{G_f} \subseteq F(\delta) \subseteq E^{G_f \cap A_n}$$

where $[E^{G_f \cap A_n} : E^{G_f}] = |G_f/(G_f \cap A_n)|$ is at most $2$.  This means that either $F(\delta) = F$ or $F(\delta) = E^{G_f \cap A_n}$.  Showing that $\delta \not\in F$ implies that $F(\delta) \neq F$, and so $F(\delta) = E^{G_f \cap A_n}$.

Comment: How did you get $[E^{G_f \cap A_n} : E^{G_f}] = |G_f/(G_f \cap A_n)| ?$

Comment: If it is from some property, can you please tell me that property.